# Who suspended householder Angus and what are the valid grounds for doing such?

Tags: discussion

Who suspended Upasaka Angus?

On what valid ground in relation the the site owners rules?

On what valid ground of dhammic rules of non-harmlessness?

Answer (score 1):

I did.

I had asked him to stop editing.

One of SE's pre-prepared moderator message templates says ...

> It has been flagged that you have asked the same question repeatedly. This is regarded as "noise" on Buddhism Stack Exchange.

... which is more-or-less applicable to this case (i.e. continually reposting only-slightly-edited versions).

[The Help](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/editing) says,

> Edits are expected to be substantial and to leave the post better than you found it.

[Also](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit)

> Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged - try to make the post significantly better when you edit, correcting all problems that you observe.

Editing a question 80+ times isn't improving it -- and it isn't "moderate" -- and I don't see how it helps anyone. The system raises flags (for moderator review) when a post is edited more than 20 times.

I had hoped that, if I overlooked it and let him to continue to edit for a few days, then he would find some 'final' version: but he has been editing for the last [two weeks now](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/posts/29621/revisions?page=3) still without stopping.

I consulted with other SE moderators (not Andrei and Lanka).

Perhaps he feels uneasy about the questions which he posted.

He has deleted [his four answers](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/users/14288/angus?tab=answers) (which isn't very bad), and deleted almost all the comments he has posted (which is allowable too), but I am [not supposed to delete](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question) his questions after other people have answered them.

I told him that it's possible to disassociate the questions from his user account (and/or to delete his user account), in case that would help him (e.g. if his unease is because the questions are associated with his user account), but he didn't reply to that suggestion.

I don't really understand the problem, only that he is not comfortable with the questions that he posted -- and I don't know a good way to solve that problem -- but I think that his continuing to make endless edits to them every day for weeks isn't a good solution either.

[What to do with users making lots of pointless edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/83471/139866) suggests ...

> This feels like abuse. If I were mod I'd shoot him an email asking him to stop (or perhaps just leave a comment asking him to stop). If the behaviour continued I'd give him a short suspension. (If it continued beyond that, I'd suspend for a longer period of time.)

... and so I've done that now. I'd prefer it if I didn't have to -- and I don't usually have to, because other users don't do that.

The [Help describes moderators](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators) as follows ...

> Moderators are human exception handlers, there to deal with those exceptional conditions that could otherwise disrupt the community.
>
> The most common moderator task is to follow up on flagged posts. Every post contains a small flag link, which anyone with 15 reputation can use. Posts can be flagged as spam, offensive, or just general “needs moderator attention” with an explanatory comment or link.

The system has raised several flags, and although I have been reluctant I think that this (e.g. a short suspension after first a polite request, and then a longer explanation, and then a warning) is a reaction that's expected of a site moderator.

I hope that a temporary suspension isn't harmful (and/or is less harmful than his continuing to make about 100 edits per week) indefinitely.

Perhaps I or other people can discuss this topic -- or, if necessary, the questions -- with him in about a week from now when the suspension expires.

Comment: Sadhu for open and careful answer, Nyom Chris. Good if Upasaka @Angus is informed about the good-will, since my person guesses it's "just" being troubled by kamma ripping, wishing to leave best formulation behind. Of course a given break can be sometimes very helpful. Not sure if there are ways to ask someone rebuked in this way before the end of such time, whether things have become better or there still desire for impossible change of previous deeds instead of walking on exists. Maybe a good habit to take on in cases suspending someone, to inform others and the target, generally.

Comment: In regard of deleting, good if searching for alternatives.

Comment: And "I'd prefer it if I didn't have to", is something which should be abound. Nobody forces one to do things and never is there a real reason that requires harm of one self or others. He continued to do exactly be cause thinking that he has to do it perfect fist before abounding it as well. Prefer of what is skilfull is always the better choice, always. All else causes suffering and remorse. Once done wrong, seeing a fault pardon it, resoving not to do it again, ones is purified and free and able to walk on.